# JAXB : create the XML Attributes dynamically based on the values

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I've strange requirement for generation of a XML document. I need to add the xml attributes based on the value of other tags.

In the below xml, for Row tags, I need to display **Column1** values based on the values in `<table>` tag. Like two dimensional matrix.

Ex: If I have value in my `<table>` like 
`<table name="table1"  row="1" column="1" >`

Then in my `<Row>` tag I need to add attribute like : `Column1` (Column tag attribute name) `= "table1"` (table tag attribute name)

I'm generating the value for this association but How can I create on the fly tags xmlAttribute like this?

I need to generate my XML in this way..

```
<Tree name="" desc="" title="" >
    <Column>
         <Column name="Column1" desc="" group="" id="1"/>
    </Column>
    <Row>
        <Row id =1 name=" " desc="" =""  Column1 = "table1">
           <Row id = 2 name="" desc=""   Column1 = "table2" />
        </Row>
        <Row id = 3 name=" " desc="" id="" Column1 = "table3" />
    </Rows>
    <table>
         <table name="table1"  row="1" column="1" > 
         <table name="table2"  row="2" column="1" > 
          <table name="table3"  row="3" column="1" > 
    </table>
</Tree>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to write a class for marshalling with attributes having arbitrary names.

```
public class Row {
  private Map<QName,Object> any;
  private String name;
  private String type;

  @XmlAnyAttribute
  public Map<QName,Object> getAny(){
    if( any == null ){
      any = new HashMap<QName,Object>();
    }
    return any;
  }

  @XmlAttribute
  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }
  public void setName( String value ){
    name = value;
  }
  @XmlAttribute
  public String getType(){
    return type;
  }
  public void setType( String value ){
    type = value;
  }
}
```

If you don't have a namespace in use, setting an attribute goes like this:

```
Row r1 = new Row();
r1.getAny().put( new QName( "Column1" ), "table1" );
```